# Creating CSS3 dropdown menus on a horizontal navbar with a fade-in effect

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've been trying to get this right for a couple of days now, and so far, I haven't really made progress on getting the dropdown working at all, though partly because the guides I've read all make use of symbols in the CSS that I'm unfamiliar with, such as the tilde and 'greather than' symbols. In any case, here is the base code that I have:

```
<nav class="bg">
    <ul class="width">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="link">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="link">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.width{margin:0 auto;min-width:1000px;width:84%;}
nav ul{width:100%;text-align:justify;font-size:0;position:relative;}
nav ul:after{content:"";width:100%;display:inline-block;}
nav li{list-style:none;display:inline-block;}
nav a{display:inline-block;padding:10px;}
```

I think the next step is to put `display:none;` on the inner `<ul>` elements to hide them by default, but the next part is where I get lost. How do you use CSS to make one object do something when something else happens to another object? In this case, how would you use the CSS to make the dropdown list appear when the relevant link is hovered?

Comment: Can you provide a Demo ore a fiddle or something like that?

Comment: *unfamiliar with, such as the tilde and 'greather than' symbols* so those are called as [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html), learn them and than it will start making some sense to you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GLORIEN/vBN67/)

First of all you need to understand how CSS Selectors are working.

For the way to add a Dropdown, you go for the hover on the parent element and wrap that around the sub-menu. Than if the hover event is fired everything inside will be able to select true :hover

Like:

```
.nav li:hover .sub-menu {
     left: 0;
     top: 100%;
 }
```

I also added the Fade-In effect. There for you work with css-transition. 
But be careful, if your Sub-menu will be on/off with display:block and :none it wont work i guess.

U may play around with that in that fiddle to fiddle out what you can do and how your changes effect the output.

```
.nav .sub-menu {
      position: absolute;
      left: -1000px;
      top: -1000px;
      opacity: 0;
      -o-transition: opacity .25s;
      -ms-transition:  opacity .25s;
      -moz-transition: opacity .25s;
      -webkit-transition: opacity .25s;
      transition: opacity .5s;
}

.nav li:hover .sub-menu {
      left: 0;
      top: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Code works perfectly, but 30 minutes later, I'm still confused with some of the selectors. I need to go make some random things to learn by example. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just go true the list in the html und look what there is matching in CSS.

Comment: One other thing...Why does a fade out not work? Is there some sort of limitation with CSS? From what I've seen, it looks like the only practical solution is javascript.

Comment: In my Demo it works fine. I just Updated it so check latest Version, my first Version was without a fade-out.

Comment: Oh, great! Wonder why the pages I read said it couldn't be one, then...In any case, thanks once again.

Comment: What Page? And you'r Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can even create a dropdown without using any selectors. But it is important to know about selectors. Go through **[this link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)** to know more about selectors.

You can have a look at **[Pure CSS Dropdown Menu](http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/11/pure-css-dropdown-menu.html)** to check how to create dropdown menu with css.

Answer (score 0):

You have yourself correctly pointed out the problem and that is :

> How do you use CSS to make one object do something when something else
>   happens to another object?

I think this simplest [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/5g84N/), would shed some light on your above question.

Specifically have a deeper look at below CSS in the demo.

```
#circle:hover .popup{
    display : block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do you use CSS to make one object do something when something else happens to another object? In this case, how would you use the CSS to make the dropdown list appear when the relevant link is hovered?

```
li > a ul { display: none; }
li > a:hover ul { display: block; }
```

You can also play [with transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) to add fade-in effect.